# TypeError: google.search.Search.apiary18984 is not a function error in firefox only

Tags: javascript, google-search-api

We have a google search api that seems to work in every browser except in firefox.This error shows up in the developer console. TypeError: google.search.Search.apiary18984 is not a function.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like we got it to work. For some reason we had the script on the page twice. Removing one of them will fix your issue.